# how to type Record classes and instances?

Tags: immutable.js, flowtype

I understand that [Record](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) creates a new class. Why then does the following typecheck in Flow:

```
const Person  = Record({fname       : null, lname: null});
const Person2 = Record({fnameMANGLED: null, lname: null});        
const p : Person2 = new Person({fname: 'joe', lname: 'doe'}); // shouldn't Flow complain?
```

In contrast, when using ordinary classes, the following doesn't typecheck (as expected):

```
class A{constructor() {}};
class B{constructor() {}};        
const a: A = new A();
```

Answer (score 3):

As of `v4.0.0-rc.5` they added types `RecordOf<T>` and `RecordFactory<T>`.

Here is a snippet from the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) on how to use these flow types.

```js
import type { RecordFactory, RecordOf } from 'immutable';

// Use RecordFactory<TProps> for defining new Record factory functions.
type Point3DProps = { x: number, y: number, z: number };
const makePoint3D: RecordFactory<Point3DProps> = Record({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 });
export makePoint3D;

// Use RecordOf<T> for defining new instances of that Record.
export type Point3D = RecordOf<Point3DProps>;
const some3DPoint: Point3D = makePoint3D({ x: 10, y: 20, z: 30 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the current type definitions of immutable JS, [Record factory constructor](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/immutable.js.flow#L651) returns `any`.

If you uncomment the line `/*T & Record<T>*/` it [catches the error as expected](https://tryflow.org/?code=LyogQGZsb3cgKi8KZGVjbGFyZSBjbGFzcyBSZWNvcmQ8VDogT2JqZWN0PiB7CiAgICBzdGF0aWMgPFQ6IE9iamVjdD4oc3BlYzogVCwgbmFtZT86IHN0cmluZyk6IFQgJiBSZWNvcmQ8VD4gLy8gYW55Owp9Cgpjb25zdCBQZXJzb24gID0gUmVjb3JkKHtmbmFtZSAgICAgICA6IG51bGwsIGxuYW1lOiBudWxsfSk7CmNvbnN0IFBlcnNvbjIgPSBSZWNvcmQoe2ZuYW1lTUFOR0xFRDogbnVsbCwgbG5hbWU6IG51bGx9KTsgICAgICAgIApjb25zdCBwIDogUGVyc29uMiA9IG5ldyBQZXJzb24oe2ZuYW1lOiAnam9lJywgbG5hbWU6ICdkb2UnfSk7IC8vIHNob3VsZG4ndCBGbG93IGNvbXBsYWluPw==).